# JSHint: How do disable the check for unsafe characters for comments?

Tags: jslint, jshint

When using "unsafe characters" (e.g. umlauts) in comments I get the following error:

```
This character may get silently deleted by one or more browsers.
```

Is there any way to disable this check for comments (globally)?

Comment: "messy white space" , don't know why but that's the one.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: unfortunately does not work for me: `white: false` gives me the exact same error messages, `white: true` results in many additional errors on top.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I fixed it in one specific file by adding `/* jshint -W100 */` in the top of the file.

To ignore it globally, I guess you have to add it somewhere in `.jshintrc` (though I don't know where).

Comment: This will disable the check completely though, not just for comments.

Answer (score 15):

I was able to fix this problem by saving the document as UTF-8.

I have several files all created the same way, three of them are giving me this error using gulp + jslint, I dont know why but I managed to get rid of the error in Sublime Text by going to:

```
File > Save with Encoding > UTF-8
```

Errors magically disappear!

Comment: In Visual Studio, select File -> Advanced Save Options... -> Choose 'Unicode (UTF-8 with signature).."

Comment: Correction, in Visual Studio, select File -> Advanced Save Options... -> Choose 'Unicode (UTF-8 _without_ signature)...'

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem as follows ...
in jshint.js change the lines

```
char = this.scanUnsafeChars();

if (char >= 0) {
     this.trigger("warning", 
     { code: "W100", line: this.line, character: char });
}
```

to

```
char = this.scanUnsafeChars();

if (char >= 0) {
  var inCommentW100 = this.inComment ||
    startsWith.call(inputTrimmed, "//") ||
    startsWith.call(inputTrimmed, "/*");

  if(!inCommentW100) {
     this.trigger("warning", 
        { code: "W100", line: this.line, character: char });
  }
}
```